# Unsigned comparison. SETB command in assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm reading "Computer Systems A Programmer's Perspective" by Bryant & O'Hallaron.

In a section regarding comparisons, it states that `SETB Dest` command sets destination to 1 if previous `cmpq A, B` command result between unsigned values is lower than 0.

It also states that in other words, it sets destination value to value of CF (Carry flag) bit.

But I have a doubt, a counter-example and a question.

Consider following C function:

```
char cmp_u(unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
  return (a < b);
}
```

It's generated with `gcc` assembly code looks like this:

```
cmpb    %sil, %dil
setb    %al
ret
```

So it's evaluates `a - b` first with `cmpb` command and sets flags according to result. And then (according to book) sets return value to 1 if `CF` is set and 0 otherwise.

Now consider that `a = 1` and `b = 2` (a < b). In bits `a = 0000 0001` and `b = 0000 0010` and `-b = 1111 1110`. Therefore `a - b = 0000 0001 + 1111 1110 = 1111 1111`. As you see, this operation produced no carry out bit, so CF must be set to zero. And that's a contradiction.

Consider an opposite case: `a = 2` and `b = 1`. `a - b = 0000 0010 + 1111 1111 = 1 0000 0001`. There is carry out bit and therefore CF must be set to 1. Again, contradiction.

Examples above show that `setb` should set 1 to destination when CF = 0 and 0 otherwise.

And a question:
What happens when most significant bit of `b` is set to 1? Like when `b = 128 = 1000 0000 (bit representation)`?

Comment: That's not how it works. Negating b would turn it into a non unsigned char. The subtraction underflows and thus sets the carry bit.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError How is b negated?

Comment: In the x86 architecture, the carry flag indicates borrow for subtractions (which is what a `cmp` is). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag#Carry_flag_vs._borrow_flag for a bit of details.

Comment: You show the subtraction as first negating b, then adding the two together. That's not how the chip does it.

Comment: about 128 .. keep in mind the subtraction is same for both signed and unsigned values, i.e. simple (1 - 128 = 129 in 8 bit math) is calculated, nothing special happens. (the subtraction on x86 operates with bit patterns, and does the subtraction directly, not as addition)

Comment: @Michael Thanks for link. Now I seem to understand. My approach shown in question is one used in System/360,[2] 6502, MSP430, ARM and PowerPC processors and yields inverse results for CF flag. How does x86 subtract then? Does ALU performs it with borrowing starting from least significant bit?